# is it semantic/acceptable to put paging (NEXT/LAST, etc) links in a <tfoot> of a statistical table element?

Tags: html, semantics, w3c

having trouble deciding whether or not it makes sense to put paging information about a stats table in a <tfoot> element of the table.

information like "Page 1 of 13" and links to "next" & "prev," etc.

[w3c <table> reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html) & examples don't do <tfoot> justice, IMO.

so, doing something like:

```
<table>
<caption>Stats Table!</caption>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <a href="">prev pg</a>  <a href="">next pg</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>x</td>
        <td>y</td>
        <td>z</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

with some minor styling looks like *[this (click for example on jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/marcsmith/2c9zC/)*

does this seem to fit into proper semantics of html tables?  any references as to why or why not?

Comment: why is your `tfoot` **ABOVE** your `tbody` declaration?  That seems off if we're going for semantics, here.  I mean, it just seems weird to me.  I know that's how it's SUPPOSED to be.

Comment: @rockerest From the HTML spec: "TFOOT must appear before TBODY within a TABLE definition so that user agents can render the foot before receiving all of the (potentially numerous) rows of data."

Comment: @Blindy i'm sorry for causing you problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say yes, that would be acceptable.

Traditionally, the `<tfoot>` is usually used to duplicate header information when a table must be broken across boundaries (think printed pages and things of that nature). It also can be used as a static footer when the `<tbody>` elements are rendered in a scrolling panel. I believe that is close enough to what you're trying to do.

As a side note, I'm glad to see you've placed the `<tfoot>` before the `<tbody>`. I can't begin to count how many times I see people put it at the bottom.

Comment: agreed that the scrolling panel example is similar to what i'm trying to achieve.  i think it makes more sense now for me to go ahead with it.  thx for the reassurance, Michael. :)

Comment: In HTML5 `tfoot` should go after `tbody` ([WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-table-element), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tfoot#try_it).

Answer (score 0):

In general I agree with the accepted answer, but there's one exception: If you are on a small screen device and use `overflow-x: auto` for horizontal scrolling of the table, then you may (or may not) want your prev/next actions to stay visible - independent of the horizontal scroll position of the table.